# how do I divide an image into blocks in python?

Tags: python, keras

I am using keras and I want to read an image in my code and then divide it into 32x32 non-overlapping blocks and send each block into my learned deep learning model for further processing. how can I do it? during learning, I used CIFAR10 for training which has images with size 32x32. now I want to load Lena and then divide it into 32x32 blocks and send to my model for processing. do I need to do some changes on Lena to achieve correct accuracy? Thank you.

```
lena=Image.open('E:/images/lena_gray_512.tif')
a=view_as_blocks(lena_part, (32,32))
```

error:

> a=view_as_blocks(lena_part, (32,32)) Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       a=view_as_blocks(lena_part, (32,32))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\shape.py",
>   line 82, in view_as_blocks
>       if block_shape.size != arr_in.ndim:
>
> AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: what happens if the image dimensions are not divisible by 32

Comment: my images are 512x512 and I do not have any problem with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [view_as_blocks](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks)

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks

view_as_blocks(arr, (2,2))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: I put my code and error above. please tell me what is the problem? thanks

Comment: please share the code and please share what is the type of "TiffImageFile"

use python's built-in function type

Comment: I find out the problem because after using imread my image is an image object, not an array so first I change it to an array using this:lena_part=img_as_int(lena_part)

Comment: Great. I suspected as much.